# Can the pg_search full-text-search (tsearch) do both prefix and dictionary searching at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-search

I've been fiddling with pg_search. Using tsearch, I have managed to set up a dictionary search and a prefix search. However, if I search by a dictionary term, it won't also yield the results for the prefix search. I was wondering if there is a way to have them both work simultaneously.

For example, a line in my dictionary looks something like this:

> wheat grain food bread

If I search for "bread" everything titled "wheat" "grain" "food" or "bread" will appear.

But if I had an item titled "breadman" it should appear when "bread" is searched, because prefix search is true. But it doesn't unless I remove the dictionary or type a partial word like "brea" or "breadma".

Code for referenece:

```
  pg_search_scope :search_title, lambda { |query, params| 
    {
      query: query,
      against: :title,
      using: {
        tsearch: {
            dictionary: 'english', prefix: true
        }
      }
    }
```

As mentioned above, I have tried having both dictionary and prefix working at the same time. However it does not appear that prefix works if a dictionary item is searched for.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what pg_search is doing, but you can use a synonym dictionary.

- create a file `mysyn.syn` in the `tsearch_data` subdirectory of the PostgreSQL "share" directory containing

  ```
  wheat bread
  grain bread
  food bread
  ```
- create a synonym dictionary:

  ```
  CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY mysyn (
     TEMPLATE = synonym,
     SYNONYMS = mysyn
  );
  ```
- create a text search configuration:

  ```
  CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mycf (COPY = english);
  ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION mycf
     ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword WITH mysyn, english_stem;
  ```

That should work as desired for prefix search:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('mycf', 'food') @@ to_tsquery('mycf', 'bread:*');

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)

SELECT to_tsvector('mycf', 'breadbox') @@ to_tsquery('mycf', 'bread:*');

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the dictionary I was talking about in my question IS a synonym dictionary, and it was created like this.

However the contents are slightly different. You have 3 lines for 3 synonyms, I have them all in one line like this:
wheat grain food bread

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work. Look at the documentation.

Comment: My dictionary doesn't work? It actually does. And yes it works like that because the documentation has their dictionary in the same one line format [sleep, sleeping, sleeps]

https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search?tab=readme-ov-file#dictionary

Regardless. It's not a big deal, I have decided I do not need the dictionary and prefix to work at the same time. Thanks for all the help though! :)

Comment: Ok, I meant: it doesn't work with PostgreSQL full text search. I don't know what pg_search is or does. The configuration file for PostgreSQL synonym dictionaries only supports two words per line.

Comment: Ah my apologies, I may have misinterpreted your previous comment.